# Get a href attr and set it to another

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('.thelink a').select(function() {

        var a_href = $(this).attr("href");

    });
    $('.calltoActionMoreInformation a').attr('href', a_href);
});
</script>

  <div class="thelink" style="height: 250px; position: relative;">
  <a title="xxx" href="xxx">
    <img alt="tree" src="x" />

  </a>
  </div>
```

Trying to put the href from a  inside  into:

```
  <span class="calltoActionMoreInformation" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
   <a title="" href="--Link here--"></a>
  </span>
```

If I set var a_href = 'http://www.google.co.uk'; it sets it correctly, so the problem lies within getting the href of the only a link within .thelink div..

How do I assigned the href in .thelink a to .calltoActionMoreInformation a **?**

Comment: What? What is your question? I see no question mark ;-)

Comment: How do I assigned the href in .thelink a to .calltoActionMoreInformation a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - the variable "a href" is not accessible from the global context, but only the select function.

2 - why use "select" function "click" is more appropriate in this case

correction :

```
$(function(){

    $('.thelink a').click(function(e) {
        $('.calltoActionMoreInformation > a').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
            e.preventDefault(); // or
        return false; // this is important is you dont want the browserfollow the link
    });

});
```

is it right ?

Comment: Can I only get the href with an event like click, not just get it in a foreach or anthing?

Comment: hi, please can you clarify your last question ?

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.thelink a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var a_href = $(this).attr("href"); // or this.href
   $('.calltoActionMoreInformation a').attr('href', a_href);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/197/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thelink a').click(function() {
   var a_href = $(this).attr("href");
   $('.calltoActionMoreInformation a').attr('href', a_href);
   return;
});
```